# What is the git equivalent for a specific version checkout, like "svn checkout -r 123 <svn_rep_url>"

Tags: svn, git, version-control, repository

What would be the closest git command equivalent to a svn command: "svn checkout -r 123 "?

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout -b myBranch <SHA1_for_r123>
```

You would update your working tree with the right SHA1 revision, while creating a branch in order to isolate any new commit you will make in that branch.

If you only did:

```
git checkout <SHA1_for_r123>
```

you would end up in a **[detached `HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714)** mode.

Comment: @eckes: thanks :) I actually completed the answer since you made that vote.

Comment: @VonC It looks like you are racking up points at roughly 2k a week. I could have sworn you were on 477k when you answered my last query. At this rate there will be no points left for the rest of us very soon :)

Comment: @vfclists that's what is neat with Stack Overflow: there will *always* be more than enough points for everybody else :)